# Don't get the value after submitting form

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 Switches in my form. Each switch has its own default value (one is checked, and another not). The issue appears when i try to submit the form without changing the switches, because i get undefined for each switch, in console. 
How to get the values if the user won't change the switches and will click on submit button?

link to code: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-ant-design-demo-o3kro?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ant. But using plain HTML `inputs` you'd have two choices there:

1. Having a default values content and use that if a value is not defined.

```
// Outside component
const DEFAULTS = {
    test2: false,
    test: true,
}

//Inside component
const onFinish = values => {
    const { test2 = DEFAULTS.test2, test = DEFAULTS.test } = values
    console.log("Success:", { test2, test });
};

// Don't forget to change de `defaultChecked` prop for these values as well.
```

2. Using [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) using some state.

I would suggest option 2 since this is a clear use case for a controlled component.